# Can access simple react state but not props

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React so this may be simple to fix, but I cannot access {this.props.AvgRating} in the ReviewsTotalStars.js file. I'm having to use the following state code to access a variable called `ratingStars`:

```
this.state = {
      ratingStars: 3.5
    };
```

But I don't want to use the above ratingStars, and would instead prefer to use the props.AvgRating. Why cannot I access it? Here is my simple code:

index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReviewsLeftArea from "./ReviewsLeftArea";
import "./style.css";

const avgRating = 3.5;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ReviewsLeftArea AvgRating={avgRating} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

ReviewsLeftArea.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReviewsTotalStars from "./ReviewsTotalStars";

export default class ReviewsLeftArea extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReviewsTotalStars avgRating={this.props.AvgRating} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ReviewsTotalStars.js:

```
import React from "react";

export default class ReviewsTotalStars extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ratingStars: 3.5
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.ratingStars} works but this {this.props.AvgRating} doesn't
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help and explanations here.

Comment: constructor is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ReviewsTotalStars you want to access:

```
this.props.AvgRating
```

But it is actually:

```
this.props.avgRating
```

By the way, you should not have a props that starts with an upper case letter

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple to fix, in react, you should never create vaiables outside of the class you are working on, instead you should add them to the state object, like this:

Index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReviewsLeftArea from "./ReviewsLeftArea";
import "./style.css";

// const avgRating = 3.5;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      avgRating: 3.5;
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ReviewsLeftArea AvgRating={this.state.avgRating} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

ReviewsTotalStars.js:

```
import React from "react";

export default class ReviewsTotalStars extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       {this.props.avgRating} //now this should work
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no problem, i recommend you mosh's free react crash course, it really helped me in my beginning.